# google sheets + scripts conditional formatting

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a custom formula in google scripts bringing some integers into my sheet from an external web service.

```
function getDecimal() {

    return [
       [1.111.toFixed(2),
        2.222.toFixed(2),
        3.333.toFixed(2),
        4.444.toFixed(2)]
    ];
}
```

I have conditional formatting applied to the sheet/cell (cell range actually), but it doesnt seem to take effect when the value comes from my custom =getInteger(A1) function.

I have tried returning text, integer and float (via parseFloat) but nothing has worked. Is this just a google sheets bug?

Comment: It's not clear to me what your problem is. Is it possible to see more of your code? And possibly a copy of your spreadsheet.

Comment: Conditional formatting does work with your code, I just tried it.  Maybe post what your conditional formatting is to make your question clear.

Comment: i have edited my example